# Are there any windows softphones that support "mute all other sounds" on calls

Tags: windows-7, audio, softphone

Are there any softphones that do as the title asks?

We've been using 3CX and I've tried Blink, EKiga, X-Lite and a few more which I have forgotten the name of. I can't seem to find any softphone that supports the windows "Mute all other sounds" Or the reduction to 80% etc that you find on the communication tab. The only program I know that does this right is Skype, but skype can't connect to SIP (without an extra service that they charge for). My boss isn't against buying a license for a product, but I don't think he'd go for a contract or per-use fee based product.

I thought X-Lite did the job, but it turns out it only pauses the media player. This wouldn't be that bad except if you have audio coming out of a browser. It doesn't deal with that.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the answer you're looking for, but in Windows7, you can quickly mute all applications except specifically selected ones:

1. Open the audio mixer.
2. Mute the master volume (main speaker)
3. *Un*-mute the volume control for the specific application you want to hear audio from.

This will have the effect you're looking for with any application that plays audio; the primary drawback is that when you're done, you'll need to manually un-mute all of the other applications in the mixer.